# Angular or Sails.js or LoopBack not working with ZSH in Ubuntu?

Tags: angular, sails.js, zsh, loopbackjs, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install Javascript Frameworks like Angular, LoopBack or SailsJS but It doesn't work with ZSH. 
I am trying to run commands to build the projects but It doesn't include in the ZSH.
How to include them like

`ng new App`
`sails new App`
`lb4 new App`
all of these commands don't include in ZSH terminal.
Ubuntu 19.04

error message: `ng new App` 
`zsh: command not found: ng`

Comment: are you sure you have access to nodejs commands? try node -v and tell us the results

Comment: I solve it by install Node JS 10.16.0 LTS on ZSH again and install Angular, Sails or LoopBack again

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install packages CLI first using `npm install -g` (e.g. `npm install -g @angular/cli`).

Since node@5.2.0 you can also use [`npx`](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner) (e.g. `npx ng new App`) before your command which will use your local dependency or download the actual package if the dependency is not installed.